# Error when fetching multiple values in JMeter JSON Extractor

Tags: jmeter

I have a JSON Response that is of the below format:

```js
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "_id": 270582,
    "_type": "Example",
    "_tasklist": [{
      "_id": "m1mv27r8upy2bta982jme3bp",
      "writable": true
    }]
  }
}
```

I am trying to fetch the request Id (data._id) & task list id (data._tasklist[0]._id) in JMeter using JSON Extractor as below and use in the subsequent requests using ${instanceid} & ${taskid}
[image]

This is not successful. However if I try to fetch just the instance id, it does substitute the value for instance id in the following requests. I did try a few suggestions from the SO answers but they have not solved my issue. What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, The issue was that the default values should have been specified.
I fixed it as below :
[image]

Checked the logs and there it showed what the issue was!

facepalm moment :(